# MSN Can not connect, error 800488fe

Tags: windows-live-messenger, hotmail

Q:

I usually sign in `MSN` , and every thing is okay ,but yesterday when i tried to sign in as usual i get the following error `800488fe` and can't sign in at all , i tried to sign in even with my browser but in vain . my mail was from 2006 and i store critical data in ,how to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your account has been desactivated, follow [those intructions to reactivate it](http://windowslivehelp.com/solution.aspx?solutionid=98273f47-0c53-440e-8a20-059570831f74)